# Disable/Enable eclipselink connection pool

Tags: spring-boot, eclipselink, connection-pooling, spring-orm

I am writing a Spring Boot application and configured Eclipselink as a JPA provider. I would like to disable Eclipselink external and internal connection pools and use tomcat to provide connection to Eclipselink.

Could you suggest is this approach is good to go? If I have to give pooling to Eclipselink control, I wouldn't be able to use spring orm and jpa features. Several things happens behind the scenes such as EntityManagerFactory and EntityManager I have to manage in application.

My questions are:

Which one is better/smooth approach with Spring Boot + Eclipselink for connection pooling.

How to disable/enable eclipselink internal or external connection pools. Looking at the documentation I couldn't get clear idea.

Thank you for your help!

Below is my eclipselink configuration:

```
public class EclipseLinkJpaConfig extends JpaBaseConfiguration {

@Override
protected AbstractJpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter() {
    final EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
    return adapter;
}

@Override
protected Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties() {
    final HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.WEAVING, "static");
    map.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.DEPLOY_ON_STARTUP, "true");
    map.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.TARGET_SERVER, "config.ConnectionPlatform");
    return map;
}
```

}

Data source config in application.properties below:

```
spring.datasource.initial-size=5
spring.datasource.max-wait=30000 
spring.datasource.max-active=10
spring.datasource.max-idle=10
spring.datasource.min-idle=5
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
```

Comment: You are thinking way to complex. Just configure a `LocalContainerEntitymanagerFactory`, configure it for EclipseLink and just pass in the `DataSource` instead of configuring that in eclipse link. And be done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Deinum. I have done the same in Spring boot application. Configured datasource via application.properties spring.datasource.** . Could see eclipselink is making a JNDI look up on tomcat datasource connection pool by default. Just thought of knowing is this the best approach to make application in Production.

Comment: Only defining a datasource isn't enough, yu still have to properly configure a `LCEMF` for eclipse link else nothing will happen.

Comment: Yep. We use Spring boot which comes with ORM/JPA Adaptors. Below is the code base which creates LCMF. Do we need to do any other set up with Spring JPA. Thanks for your patience.

@Configuration
public class EclipseLinkJpaConfig extends JpaBaseConfiguration {
    protected AbstractJpaVendorAdapter createJpaVendorAdapter() {
        final EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        return adapter;
    }

    protected Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties() {
        <<some config maps>>
        return map;
    }

Comment: Followed https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Spring

Please mention any more specific config required. Thank you.

Comment: That page is over 6 years old and contains imho dated information. Also don't add code as comments, improve your question. Please add your configuration to your question.

Comment: Thanks Deinum. Added Spring boot + Eclipse JPA code configuration to this question. please have a look and suggest production like configurations needs to be set.